# cURL with SSL dependency error libssl.so libcrypto.so needed in Ubuntu 32bit

Tags: php, curl, ssl, openssl, ubuntu-10.10

I had my 64bit Ubuntu have no problems when I installed openssl, curl and PHP with commands

OpenSSL

```
./configure enable-shared
```

cURL

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-zlib
```

PHP

```
./configure .... --with-openssl --with-curl ....
```

But in my 32bit Ubuntu, the installation stopped at the cURL level when I ran the

```
make
```

command

Here is the error I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.0.0, needed by ../lib/.libs/libcurl.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.1.0.0, needed by ../lib/.libs/libcurl.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

I went through /usr/local/ssl directory and did found the two files which are claimed to be missing. I don't know what's happening here. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem, it was so silly of me to overlook cURL's website documentation.
All I had to do was pass in the environment variable for the run time linker to use the shared libraries before configure.

```
env LDFLAGS=-R/usr/local/ssl/lib ./configure --with-ssl --with-zlib
```

..and it worked without any issues. I now have https support in even Ubuntu 32bit.
Here's the documentation link http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html